# rust-analyzer failed to discover workspace in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-extensions, rust-analyzer

I'm starting to learn the Rust language and I have an issue with `rust-analyzer` vscode extension.

- It doesn't provide code completion as shown in the link: https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#magic-completions
- Vscode shows notification as shown in the picture below: [image]

This picture doesn't provide me with any additional info about root of the problem. I tried to find articles related to my error, but failed. Please help!

**UPD1.**

Screenshot of directory:

[image]

Screenshot of **Cargo.toml** contents:

[image]

guessing_game directory was created with `cargo new guessing_game` command

Comment: What does your file structure look like and what's the output of `cargo check` when ran from the root of your project?

Comment: That is ```cargo check``` output:
```Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s```
And that's how my file looks like:
https://pastebin.com/uzb4iUU5

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to provide (1) a screenshot of how your project looks in VS Code's Explorer sidebar, (2) a listing of filenames as text, and (3) the contents of your project's `Cargo.toml` file? The problem here will have something to do with the file layout, *not* the Rust source code, because rust-analyzer only works when it finds a Cargo workspace/package and that's what the error is telling you.

Comment: @KevinReid, I've added screenshots for (1) and (3), but what do you mean by **a listing of filenames as text**?

Comment: Also I've tried to turn on official rust extension(as far as I know, it's deprecated) and turn off **rust-analyzer**. Now I have code completion and other features. But I still want to solve the issue and use **rust-analyzer**.

Comment: By "listing of filenames" I meant the kind of info that's in the screenshot (1) — all the file and directory names in your project, and what directories the files are in. I see the problem has been resolved, but the advantage of providing the information as text is that it can be easily copied and edited, for precise discussion of what the difference between what you have and what you need is.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I guess you don't have a `Cargo.toml` file in your project? The `rust-analyzer` needs a `Cargo.toml` to detect the workspace.

You could create a new rust project with `cargo`:

```sh
cargo new your-project
```

`cargo` will help you create a `Cargo.toml` file automatically, or you could manually create a `Cargo.toml` for your existing project.

If this issue keep popping up, perhaps you could check this [Github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/7268) for help.

Edit:

You should open your project like this, instead of opening the parent directory of `guessing_game`. Just try the following steps:

1. `cargo new guessing_game_v2`;
2. then in VSCode, Choose "File" -> "Open Folder.." -> Choose the new `guessing_game_v2` folder
3. and check if it works?

[image]

You should make sure that your `Cargo.toml` is in the root of workspace.

Comment: I have it. I've updated my question with screenshots.

Comment: I think I found  your problem, you should open `guessing_game` folder, and make `Cargo.toml` in the root project

Comment: but Isn't ```Cargo.toml``` at the root already? (as depicted on screenshot above)

Comment: > but Isn't Cargo.toml at the root already? No, it's in `{project_root}/guessing_game/Cargo.toml`, you should make it to `{project_root}/Cargo.toml`

Comment: But ```/guessing_game``` is root directory of project. Parent directory of ```guessing_game``` is ```rust```, so it looks like this: ```rust/guessing_game```. I've tried to move ```Cargo.toml``` to ```rust/Cargo.toml```, but cargo commands(such as cargo build/check) don't work anymore.

Comment: Would you like to just give it a try: 1.`cargo new guessing_game_v2`; 2. then in VSCode, Choose "File" -> "Open Folder.."  -> Choose the new `guessing_game_v2` folder, 3. and check if it works?

Comment: it worked! I've tried to create new folder with ```cargo new guessing_game```, then open it via vscode **Open Folder** and now it is okay. Previously I've tried to work with directory which is used for a number of programming languages. Thank you!

Comment: could you edit your answer, so i can mark it as one that solved my problem?

Comment: This is wrong. Why should you have ONE cargo.toml. The way to use vscode is to open the top level folder across all your projects ever. In there will be many Cargo.toml and whatever else. This is how all extensions MUST work. Opening one vscode per lang project is crazy. How can we avoid this error?

Comment: To avoid having to put `Cargo.toml` in the workspace root, just use the `rust-analyzer.linkedProjects` setting to specify the path(s) to your `Cargo.toml` file(s) (one or more). Like so: `"rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": ["./guessing_game/Cargo.toml"]`. Assuming that your workspace root is the parrent of `guessing_game`, this should work just fine.

Comment: Use cargo init if you want it in your current directory.

Comment: Or `cargo init` if the folder already exists and you're init, then just restart the Rust Analyser server via the command palette in vscode

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error and resolved it as follows:

**Background**

- I had installed VSCode extension `rust-lang.rust-analyzer`
- I had my projects in subfolders of the root project folder. i.e.

```
projects
  > guessing_game
    > src
      main.rs
    > target
      > debug
        guessing_game
    Cargo.lock
    Cargo.toml
rust-toolchain
```

- I was using VSCode Remote Explorer to access the code via SSH
- *But I had the same error `rust-analyzer failed to discover workspace`.*

**Solution**

I did the following to resolve it:

- Updated VSCode to latest Version: 1.75.1 (Universal)
- Uninstalled the deprecated VSCode extension `rust-lang.rust`
- Updated to replacement VSCode extension Rust Analyser `rust-lang.rust-analyzer` v0.3.1426
- Updated to VSCode extension Remote Extension `ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack` v0.24.0
- Updated to VSCode extension CodeLLDB `vadimcn.vscode-lldb` v1.8.1
- Updated the rust-toolchain file in the root of the project directory so its contents had the latest version of Rust:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2023-03-05"
components = ["rust-src"]
```

- Ran `rustup update`
- Removed the projects/guessing_game/Cargo.lock file and the projects/guessing_game/target folder
- Added a Cargo.toml file to the project root directory with the following contents (retained the existing Cargo.toml file in the project directory):

```
[workspace]

members = [
    "projects/guessing_game",
]
```

- Ran `cargo build` from the project root directory (the folder above the projects/ directory). The new folder structure was now:

```
projects
  > guessing_game
    > src
      main.rs
    Cargo.toml
> target
  > debug
    guessing_game
Cargo.toml
rust-toolchain
```

- Restarted VSCode after each of the above actions
- No more rust-analyser error

Comment: The `Cargo.toml` file in the project root directory with the `[workspace]` section heading was what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: I also got this linter warning when running `cargo build`:
`warning: some crates are on edition 2021 which defaults to \`resolver = "2"\`, but virtual workspaces default to \`resolver = "1"\``. To fix this, I added `resolver = "2"` underneath the `[workspace]` section heading.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry if this is going to sound vague, but it is only because it happened quickly. I was looking at the [bottom pane of vscode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6USfR.png)

And **think** because I have Prettier as well, a dialog popped up saying it doesn't support `.rs`, Anyway I am not sure how what happened next happened, but the **command-palette** popped open and it prompted:

> me make this file type the **default** for `rust-analyzer`

and then boom `rustfmt` started working.

So then I said hmmm, let's check `settings.json`

And to my glee I found this...

```
 "[rust]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer"
  }
```

Really hopes this helps anyone trying to become a rustacean!

Comment: Wow, really helpful to get things set up! Otherwise I'd imagin find myself frantically searching for how to configure rust with prettier.

Answer (score 7):

For me, specify the `rust-analyzer.linkedProjects` in the workspace worked.

```
"rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": [
    "{absolute_path}/Cargo.toml"
]
```

I think there are too many `Cargo.toml` files that confused the `rust-analyzer` so it cannot figure out which project to link.
seems that you can also specify several `Cargo.toml` at the same time, it also worked, restart the server might be needed.

[image of my workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9jRW.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you don't know what this answer is talking about, then read this. Go to the extension settings. Click on the "workspace" tab. Then, find the "linkedProjects" option. Then, go ahead an manually enter in the correct path. In my case, when I switched from windows to mac, I had to manually change the forward slashes to backslashes.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and just solved it isntalling rust-src,
just type in a terminal

```
sudo apt install rust-src
```

and then reload vscode

Comment: yeah, I had the same issue on arch resolved with `pacman -S rust-src`

Comment: I installed `rustfmt` which seems to have fixed the formatting for me.
I still get rust-analyzer errors, but the formatting on save works.

Answer (score 2):

Below worked:

1. Find the `root folder`

`root folder` is the top level directory
it can found using `View > Explorer` menu of vs code

2. In the `root folder`, run below

`cargo new your-project`

Note: `your-project` is created

3. Move all files/folders of `your-project` to their parent directory

So now, you will have below files, in your `root folder`

. `src\main.rs` and
. `Cargo.toml`

4. restart the vs code

---

That's all

Note: if above does not solve, then point 1 above ( in my case ), or other  is followed wrong, so need to redo it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, disabling the Prettier extension did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a project in that directory, just run `cargo init` in the terminal and then restart rust-analyzer server

Answer (score 0):

In vsCode if you open just your cargo package directory and **not** [image] the directory above it that may contain other cargo builds the Analyzers works perfectly with no error message.[image] [image]

Comment: Sorry folks that fix did not hold when I tested it on another computer, but good news! When I uninstall the vsCode rust-analyzer extension, restarted vsCode, then reinstalled the rust-analyzer extension it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should open the project folder, not rs source file itself. Then it'll download a few hundred MB (metadata? src?) then start working.

Tested @ Windows VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

just add the wanted folder to the workspace.

I came up with this solution by reading that "no cargo.toml file was found in ", and something about a workspace. therefore

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).