# Rust-analyzer failed to load workspace vscode

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

I know that there are a lot of similar questions regarding rust-analyzer and I've checked them out but couldn't find the solution to my problem so I decided to ask a question myself. I've decided to start learning Rust and I'm having issues with rust-analyzer.
Here is my workspace structure:
[image]

I created a project using cargo and hoped that rust-analyzer will automatically register it but for some reason it fails.
I get this error message

```
> rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: Failed to read Cargo metadata from Cargo.toml file /home/remax/Storage/Projects/rust/rusttest/hello_cargo/Cargo.toml, cargo 1.61.0 (a028ae4 2022-04-29): Failed to run `"/home/remax/.cargo/bin/cargo" "metadata" "--format-version" "1" "--manifest-path" "/home/remax/Storage/Projects/rust/rusttest/hello_cargo/Cargo.toml" "--filter-platform" "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"`: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: error: could not execute process `rustc -vV` (never executed)

Caused by:
  No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I honestly have no idea what to do.
My cargo version is 1.61.0

UPDATE: issue persists even with only rust project in workspace
[image]

Comment: What does `which cargo` say in a terminal?

Comment: @cdhowie it says ~/.cargo/bin/cargo and here is my path variable /home/remax/.local/bin:/home/remax/bin:/home/remax/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/remax/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/bin/env/:/usr/bin/env/

You think that I should add ~/.cargo/bin/cargo to path?

Comment: It already is in your path. It looks like cargo is failing to find rustc for some reason. Does `which rustc` also give a path?

Comment: @cdhowie ~/.cargo/bin/rustc here it is

Comment: I think I solved it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72062935/rust-analyzer-failed-to-discover-workspace-in-vscode

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue by deleting the .vscode folder. Reinstalling rustup didn't help.

The issue started appearing when I created a lib and then deleted it.

Comment: If deleting .vscode folder didn't help, open your xxx.code-workspace file and delete settings->rust-analyzer.linkedProjects that you find irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

The issue happens because all the workspace directories, when vscode detects those, are stored within the `<project root>/.vscode/settings.json` file, like this:

```json
{
    "rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": [
        "./Cargo.toml",
    ]
}
```

When you move your sub-crates around manually, vscode can't detect this, and change this array of `Cargo.toml`s, too. So you should open this file and manually correct the entries there so that only the existing workspaces (entries of `Cargo.toml` paths) are listed in the array.

Comment: Worked for me. The error occurred after I renamed a crate in my workspace. It was because I had added the old crate name to the "rust-analyzer.linkedProjects". After removing it, and restarting VSCode, the error went away

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Peter. Just to help you a little more, it is not necessary to restart the vscode instance. You just need to restart the rust-analyzer plugin. You can do this via the command pallette shortcut, or by selecting the option in the context menu which appears when the mouse cursor is over the "rust-analyzer" bottom bar item.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the rustup step. It is stated in the rust-analyzer extension that you need to install rustup first.

### Quick start

1. install [rustup](https://rustup.rs)
2. install the rust-analyzer extension.

Answer (score 0):

rustup must be installed in the same system as Vscode. If you are using WLS Subsystem (like me), try installing rustup on Windows with the rustup-init.exe.
Run/Debug won't work (probably - I don't know why, but there's always `cargo run`) but you'll still get all the other features.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your rust-analyzer extension to the pre-release(v0.4.1525) one. This fixed the issue on my Macbook Pro m1.

Answer (score 0):

in Rust you don't have to create the Cargo.toml file manually for a new project.
delete your current workspace then,
make a new dir eg, mkdir "home/spitfire/Documents/rust"
cd into rust
make a new project file in the root dir in this case is rust

like this "cargo new learning"
you will get an output like this      Created binary (application) `learning` package

check the learning folder it will contain Cargo.toml
go back to rust by doing ..
reload vscode and enjoy rust

Answer (score 0):

I often encounter this issue. For me this fixed it

Find `settings.json` as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49706409/1227287):

- ~/.config/Code/User on Linux
- %APPDATA%\Code\User (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\User) on Windows
- ~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/ on Mac OS X

In my case the settings file has the following lines:

```
    "rust-analyzer.cargo.autoreload": false,
    "rust-analyzer.cargo.features": [
        
    ]
```

Delete these lines and restart rust-analyer in vscode using `cmd+shift+P` and `rust-analyzer: Restart Server`